# IBM Cloud GitLab + Slack Integration: HTTP Status 400 missing_text_or_fallback_or_attachments

Tags: gitlab, ibm-cloud, slack

I am trying to connect my GitLab repository from IBM Cloud to our slack channel. I get a http status error code 400: missing_text_or_fallback_or_attachments

My response header looks like this

```
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2019 09:14:21 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Via: haproxy-www-v06s
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 fb8e6daa39bc4124e46750734008822c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: Mv3PJD_D63jNuvA4YldBtHcMNGP-1fofXQ-BxgOmBy7eqPgkjpfOKg==
```

The integration settings looks like this[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating a new webhook in GitLab or using the **Slack Notifications** integration? Only Slack Notifications are supported, some people had similar issues here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/41853#note_66355191

Comment: Hi Emily, i can't see to find any **Slack Notifications** i am using the GitLab provided by IBM Cloud (formerly known as Bluemix). I also see here that the error for the particular link is status code 500, where mine is 400 which is a bad request??

Comment: Hi again! i read somewhere on the documentation that webhooks are not supported for groups am i correct? This repository exists inside a group.